# Creating abstract Activity classes

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, abstract

I am working on creating abstract activity classes for my application that I will reuse for each activity.

1. Super Class: *android.app.Activity*
2. My Abstract Class **extends android.app.Activity**
   myActivity
3. Example activty in my application **extends myActivity**.

I will have 10-20 of these `exampleActivity`.

How can I write my abstract class (#2) to force my example class to override methods in `android.app.Activity` like `onCreate()` and `onStart()`?

Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really.

*However* you can create abstract functions myOnCreate and myOnStart and call those in your abstract class implementation of onCreate and onStart.

You might also want to make onCreate/onStart final, although it's difficult to see what the benefit is of forcing myOnCreate instead of onCreate.

Comment: While the technique presented here is a good one, I'm a bit baffled by the "Not really" in this answer. You *can* make `onCreate`, etc. abstract in an abstract subclass of `Activity`. Perhaps it's a bad idea (particularly with methods like `onBackPressed` that have non-empty default implementations that you might want to call via `super`) but it can certainly be done.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible,

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends android.app.Activity
{

    public abstract void onCreat(...);
    public abstract void onStart(...);
}

public class OtherActivity extends MyActivity
{
    public void onCreate(...)
    {
        //write your code
    }

    public void onStart(...)
    {
      //write your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nop. It's more elegant to create an interface with onCreate and onStart methods instead if you need force others to override in their implementation.

And pass the interface instance to your abstract activity class throught constructors or setters.

Comment: @user721378: I'd be interested to know how that works out with an Android Activity.

Comment: Sorry it's an activity class. Please forget about that i said about constructors or setters. You can pass interface class names through intent, but it makes everything much more complex. Why don't you just create an abstract method with a different name?